# I transferred a std::pair over a named pipe how did it work?

Tags: sockets, c++11, stl, pipe, ipc

I passed a `std::pair` over a named pipe using `read()` and `write()` functions in Linux.  I passed it by reference, and read it by reference. How did that work?  From what I know, `std::pair` is not serialized and what happens when the reference goes out of scope.  Can an object be moved, or a copy by reference?

I am confused.

I am new to C++, so my pointer and reference knowledge is a little poor, but from what I know I am passing the address over the pipe and then pointing the read side object to this new address.

Though the read side object is, well, an object, not a pointer.  So what happens to it's old/original instance?

I am writing using this code:

```
std::pair<int, somestruct> sample_pair;
write(FD, &sample_pair, sizeof(sample_pair));
```

And reading it using this code:

```
std::pair<int, somestruct> sample_pair;
read(FD, &sample_pair, sizeof(sample_pair));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT sending the *address* of the `std::pair` over the pipe at all.  You are sending the actual *content* of the `std::pair` instead.

You are passing the address of a `std::pair` instance as the starting address to `write()`, telling it to read `sizeof(sample_pair)` number of bytes starting at that initial address and write them sequentially to the pipe.  The raw bytes that are stored inside of the `std::pair` are thus written as-is over the pipe.

You are passing the address of a `std::pair` instance as the starting address to `read()`, telling it to read `sizeof(sample_pair)` number of bytes from the pipe and save them sequentially to that initial address.  The raw bytes received from the pipe are thus stored as-is inside of the `std::pair`.

That being said, sending a `std::pair` in this manner is still undefined behavior, since the actual memory layout of the `std::pair` is implementation-specific, particularly in regards to any alignment padding that may exist between the two fields.  You need to manually serialize your data into a format that is safe for crossing process boundaries, then de-serialize it on the other end.

For instance, it may be as simple as sending the two fields individually (assuming `somestruct` is self-contained (no pointers to external data) and has no alignment issues of its own), eg:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct somestruct
{
    int8_t value1;
    int16_t value2;
    int32_t value3;
    char data[256];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

```
std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;
// populate as needed...

write(FD, &(sample_pair.first), sizeof(sample_pair.first));
write(FD, &(sample_pair.second), sizeof(sample_pair.second));
```

```
std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;

read(FD, &(sample_pair.first), sizeof(sample_pair.first));
read(FD, &(sample_pair.second), sizeof(sample_pair.second));
```

Or, it may be as complex and having to flatten the content of `somestruct` into a sequential `byte[]` array before sending it, eg:

```
struct somestruct
{
    int8_t value1;
    int16_t value2;
    int32_t value3;
    std::string data;
};
```

```
std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;
// populate as needed...

std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(
  sizeof(int32_t) +
  sizeof(int8_t) +
  sizeof(int16_t) +
  sizeof(int32_t) +
  sizeof(int32_t) +
  sample_pair.second.data.length()
);

uint8_t *ptr = &buffer[0];

*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr) = htonl(sample_pair.first);
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

*reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(ptr) = sample_pair.second.value1;
ptr += sizeof(int8_t);

*reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(ptr) = htons(sample_pair.second.value2);
ptr += sizeof(int16_t);

*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr) = htonl(sample_pair.second.value3);
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr) = htonl(sample_pair.second.data.length());
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

std::copy(sample_pair.second.data.cbegin(), sample_pair.second.data.cend(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr));

int32_t len = htonl(buffer.size());
write(FD, &len, sizeof(len));
write(FD, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

```
std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;

int32_t len;
read(FD, &len, sizeof(len));
len = ntohl(len);

std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(len);
uint8_t *ptr = &buffer[0];

read(FD, ptr, len);

sample_pair.first = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr));
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

sample_pair.second.value1 = *reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(ptr);
ptr += sizeof(int8_t);

sample_pair.second.value2 = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(ptr));
ptr += sizeof(int16_t);

sample_pair.second.value3 = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr));
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

len = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(ptr));
ptr += sizeof(int32_t);

sample_pair.second.data.assign(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr), len);
```

Or, you could just send the values individually:

```
void sendInt8(int FD, int8_t value)
{
    write(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
}

void sendInt16(int FD, int16_t value)
{
    value = htons(value);
    write(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
}

void sendInt32(int FD, int32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    write(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
}

void sendStr(int FD, const std::string &value)
{
    sendInt32(FD, value.length());
    write(FD, value.c_str(), value.length());
}

...

std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;
// populate as needed...

sendInt32(FD, sample_pair.first);
sendInt8(FD, sample_pair.second.value1);
sendInt16(FD, sample_pair.second.value2);
sendInt32(FD, sample_pair.second.value3);
sendStr(FD, sample_pair.second.data);
```

```
int8_t readInt8(int FD)
{
    int8_t value;
    read(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
    return value;
}

int16_t readInt16(int FD)
{
    int16_t value;
    read(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
    return ntohs(value);
}

int32_t readInt16(int FD)
{
    int32_t value;
    read(FD, &value, sizeof(value));
    return ntohl(value);
}

std::string readStr(int FD)
{
    std::string value;
    int32_t len = readInt32(FD);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        value.resize(len);
        read(FD, &value[0], len);
    }
    return value;
}

...

std::pair<int32_t, somestruct> sample_pair;

sample_pair.first = readInt32(FD);
sample_pair.second.value1 = readInt8(FD);
sample_pair.second.value2 = readInt16(FD);
sample_pair.second.value3 = readInt32(FD);
sample_pair.second.data = readStr(FD);
```